# excel VBA web service give error METHOD OR DATAOBJECT NOT FOUND

Tags: excel, web-services, vba

I have a weird problem with an excel VBA application.

It uses a web service to connect to a mysql database.

it all runs well in most computers....however in some computers it throws an error:

ERROR WHEN COMPILING "METHOD OR DATAOBJECT NOT FOUND"

All computers are running Windows 7 and Office 2007.

Here is an example of the web service code (where the error happens)

```
Public Function wsm_get_portscountries(ByVal str_SQLQuery As String) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

   On Error GoTo wsm_get_portscountriesTrap

    Set wsm_get_portscountries = sc_WebService1.wsm_get_portscountries(str_SQLQuery)

Exit Function
wsm_get_portscountriesTrap:
    WebService1ErrorHandler "wsm_get_portscountries"
End Function
```

The error highlights the bolded part here:

sc_WebService1.**wsm_get_portscountries**(str_SQLQuery)

Has anyone encountered the same problem ?? Any ideas ??
As I said, on most computers it runs well, no problems, it only happens with some.

Thanks in advance.

additional information:
class module

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    On Error GoTo Class_Initialize_error

    Dim str_WSML As String
    str_WSML = ""

    Set sc_WebService1 = New SoapClient30

    sc_WebService1.MSSoapInit2 c_WSDL_URL, str_WSML, c_SERVICE, c_PORT, c_SERVICE_NAMESPACE
    sc_WebService1.ConnectorProperty("ProxyServer") = "<CURRENT_USER>"
    sc_WebService1.ConnectorProperty("EnableAutoProxy") = True

    Exit Sub

Class_Initialize_error:    

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check for any missing references in the VBA project?

Comment: Make your function late-bound: `Public Function wsm_get_portscountries(ByVal str_SQLQuery As String) As Object`

Comment: @jbarker, yes I checked references, none missing.

Comment: @David, yes! your solution works on MOST computers, for some reason a couple still having the problem....weird. Nevertheless you've solved most of the problems. I appreciate that.

Comment: What is sc_WebService1?

Comment: What is sc_WebService1?  And where is this instantiated.

Comment: I have ammended my original question with the class module where I use the sc_webservice1